# json schema validator java - "JSON value is of type boolean, not a JSON Schema (expected an object)"

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

My question is: I am trying to validate a JSON file with JSON schema with com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema.

This is the schema:

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "processes": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "condition": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "process": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/process"
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            },
            "required": ["condition"]
        }
    }
},
"definitions": {
    "process": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["root",
                        "child",
                        "ancestor"
                    ]
                },
                "condition": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "process": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/process"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": ["type", "condition"]
        }
    }
},
"required": ["processes"],
"title": "rules-schema"
}
```

and I always get an exception on the title.

when I use regular json schema validator on the web - it works.

any suggestions?

this is my java code. I am using an external library named com.github.fge.jsonschema

```
public static ProcessingReport isJsonValid(JsonSchema jsonSchemaNode, JsonNode jsonNode) throws ProcessingException
{
    ProcessingReport report = jsonSchemaNode.validate(jsonNode);

    return report;
```

Comment: We will need to see your java code and any classes you're trying to initialize

Comment: this is a valid JSON. please show the code you've done and states where the error (exception) occur.

Comment: I uploaded the code. I am using an external library for checking the jsons

Comment: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ go there and validate your json against Schema Draft 4 - you see that you get errors. With newer json schemas - draft 6 and 7 it validates fine. The library you use validates to schema draft 4 (according to their github page)

Comment: thanks, that's what I thought